# How to stretch flexbox across phone

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make 4 boxes appear in two ways

1. On PC/a large display have all 4 boxes an equal size taking up 25% of the page each
2. On smaller displays (once the boxes start overlapping each other), have the boxes shown in a column, with each box expanding to fill the width of the screen.

```
<div class="flex-container">
<p id="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 1</a></strong></p>

<p id="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 2</a></strong></p>

<p id="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 3 </a></strong></p>

<p id="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 4 </a></strong></p>
</div>
```

```
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: stretch;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .flex-container{
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}

  #box{
    border: 15px solid blue;
  padding: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
  }

  .box {
    border: 15px solid blue;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .flex-container {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a>Box 1</a></strong></p>
  <p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a>Box 2</a></strong></p>
  <p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a>Box 3</a></strong></p>
  <p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a>Box 4</a></strong></p>
</div>
```

In this code, I replaced the duplicate id="box" attributes with class="box". Then, I used the .box class selector in the CSS code to target those elements. This ensures that the styling is applied consistently to all the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document. So change all the ids(box) to class.

Add `.box{width: 100%}` or 25% above the media-query. It will make the box share same width in desktop.

```css
/*Add this to make sizing easier*/
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: stretch;
}
/* moved box's style here*/
.box{
  width: 100%;
  border: 15px solid blue;
  padding: 15px; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .flex-container{
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 1</a></strong></p>
<!-- changed id to class -->
<p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 2</a></strong></p>

<p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 3 </a></strong></p>

<p class="box" style="text-align: center;"><strong><a >Box 4 </a></strong></p>
</div>
```